# reverse proxy and Load balancer

Tags: apache, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, apache2.4

Here is the Apache Reverse proxy and load balancer, the website/reports url is not coming up

```
   <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        <Proxy balancer://app0102>
           BalancerMember https://serverapp01.com
           BalancerMember https://serverapp02.com
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / "balancer://app0102/"
        ProxyPassReverse "/" "balancer://app0102/"
   </IfModule>
```

if I point to single server, the website/reports url work

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
      ProxyPass / https://serverapp01.com
```

/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=1200 Keepalive=On
          ProxyPassReverse / https://serverapp01.com

Website works in both cases, Any ideas on what I am missing
Thanks
Nate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your backend server is using SessionCookie then you can use the same cookie for sticky session.

```
<Proxy balancer://app0102>
BalancerMember https://serverapp01.com route=node1 
BalancerMember https://serverapp02.com route=node2 
</Proxy>

ProxyTimeout 60
ProxyStatus On

ProxyPass /   balancer://app0102/  stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid 
ProxyPassReverse / bbalancer://app0102
```

If your backend server is not using Session Cookie then you can use route for sticky session.

```
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e;  path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED
<Proxy "balancer://app0102">
    BalancerMember https://serverapp01.com route=node1
    BalancerMember https://serverapp02.com route=node2
    ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://app0102/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://app0102/
```

Make sure that your both backend server is running.

Comment: Thank you, will check it. Appreciate for compliance.

Comment: Thank you Pandurang, yes it did.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using quotes on both source and destionation,
such as:

> ProxyPass "/" "balancer://app0102/"