# Is worker.properties is mandatory to enable load balancing and sticky session in Apache http server

Tags: apache, spring-boot, tomcat

I am configuring Http WebServer 2.4 to enable Load balancing and implementing sticky session So configured below things in httpd.conf.Do I need to create worker.properties also or Below things are enough.In some tutorials they mentioned about creating worker.properties.these routes were configured in server.xml.

```
#JkWorkersFile conf/worker.properties
JkLogFile     logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel    info

#Header add Set-Cookie: "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED 
<Proxy balancer://myclustername >
BalancerMember http://localhost:8080/benefits min=1 max=300 route=tomcat1 loadfactor=1 timeout=300 KeepAlive=On
BalancerMember http://localhost:8081/benefits min=1 max=300 route=tomcat2 loadfactor=1 timeout=300 KeepAlive=On
BalancerMember http://localhost:8082/benefits min=1 max=300 route=tomcat3 loadfactor=1 timeout=300 KeepAlive=On
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /benefits  balancer://myclustername stickysession=JSESSIONID


<Location /balancer-manager>
SetHandler balancer-manager

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from all
</Location>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do I need to create worker.properties also or Below things are enough

> > Not required.Mod_proxy_balancer and mod_jk are different load balancer technique. worker.properties used in mod_jk. Use below configuration for mod_proxy_balanncer.

```
<Proxy balancer://myclustername >
BalancerMember http://localhost:8080 min=1 max=300 route=tomcat1 loadfactor=1 timeout=300 KeepAlive=On
BalancerMember http://localhost:8081 min=1 max=300 route=tomcat2 loadfactor=1 timeout=300 KeepAlive=On
BalancerMember http://localhost:8082 min=1 max=300 route=tomcat3 loadfactor=1 timeout=300 KeepAlive=On
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /   balancer://myclustername/  stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid 
ProxyPassReverse / myclustername://myclustername/
```

Even you can achieve Stickysession without JSESSIONID.Use [reverse proxy and Load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412163/reverse-proxy-and-load-balancer/62412665#62412665) for more information. If you are facing issue with JSESSIONID then use ROUTEID.

Comment: what is app0102 that you mentioned in above configuration?

Comment: my bad typo mistake. Updated answer.

Comment: But Requests are going to port number like http://localhost:8080 But frond end we kept the load balancer so requests should go as http://localhost.

Comment: Use `ProxyPreserveHost On` before ProxyPass and test.